Connection between Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(d,ℂ)$ and C* algebra $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$
In the context of quantum mechanics, one often reads about those two algebras, the C*algebra of bounded operators $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$, and the general Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(d,ℂ)$. Now, I was wondering about the connection/difference of those.
It is known that the generalized Pauli elements constitute a basis for $\mathfrak{gl}(d,ℂ)$, and every endomorphism $V: \mathcal{H}->\mathcal{H}, V\in\mathfrak{gl}(d,ℂ)$.
At the same time, the usual operator algebra is denoted as a C*-algebra of bounded linear operators $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$.
My guess is that $\mathfrak{gl}(d,ℂ)\subset \mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$ somehow, maybe they are the group of operators that fulfill the Jacobi identity.
I would be happy if someone may explain to me the differences and comonities and connections of those two. Thank you.
